# php filetype() function doesn't work on mounted directory

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-type, zend-server-ce

I have an Ubuntu machine running zend server (CE). I have a cifs mount /mnt/disk1 but when I try to run the filetype function on that directory or any other file inside of it, I get this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  filetype(): Lstat failed for /mnt/disk1
```

Also I'm sure I'm using the correct path, because when I unmount the volume, filetype() works.

Has anyone else come across this? What's the best work around?

Comment: Could You do `$ls -ld /mnt/disk1` (in text console) before and after mount and show output?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with files on a mounted drive in Ubuntu giving the same `Warning: filetype(): Lstat failed for`... error

Comment: This can also be a symptom of SELinux getting in the way. You can determine if this is the case by running ``getenforce``. If the output is anything other than "Enforcing", then SELinux is not your problem. If you do see "Enforcing, you may wish to check the security context of the files/directories in question using ``ls -lZ somedirectory``. It must have a security context compatible with apache.

Comment: Does the problem still happen with recent kernels?